# Unable to validate elements and value from json string loaded into JsonElement with jsonElement.TryGetProperty

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.1, system.text.json

I am using .net core 3.1 and System.Text.Json.
I have a string in a sub element of a json with element claims whom i wanted to load in some .net element and then validate the keys in it

```
{
  "scope": "openid MyScop",
  "claims": "{\"premiuminfo\":{\"country\":{\"value\":\"country1\"},\"town\":{\"value\":\"town1\"},\"given_name\":{\"value\":\"given_name1\"},\"postal_code\":{\"value\":\"postal_code1\"},\"family_name\":{\"value\":\"family_name1\"},\"houseno_or_housename\":{\"value\":\"test house number\"}}}",  
}
```

I have able to load the claims object in JsonElement

```
 JsonElement o = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(s);
```

But unable to find any way to check the keys like premiuminfo , county e.t.c.

Can please someone help me in using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Were using TryGetProperty wrongly
Following is the way i were able to validate

```
string s = "{\"premiuminfo\":{\"country\":{\"value\":\"country1\"},\"town\":{\"value\":\"town1\"},\"given_name\":{\"value\":\"given_name1\"},\"postal_code\":{\"value\":\"postal_code1\"},\"family_name\":{\"value\":\"family_name1\"},\"houseno_or_housename\":{\"value\":\"houseno_or_housename1\"}}}";
//s = jwtData.ContainsKey("claims");
try
{
    JsonElement o = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(s);

    if (o.TryGetProperty("premiuminfo", out var premiuminfo))
    {
        if (!premiuminfo.TryGetProperty("name", out var _) && (!premiuminfo.TryGetProperty("given_name", out var _) || !premiuminfo.TryGetProperty("family_name", out var _)))
        {
            processingResult = new ProcessingResultObject { ErrorResult = new ErrorResult { error = ErrorTypes.invalid_request.ToString(), error_description = "name or given_name, family_name is missing in claims" }, StatusCode = 400 };
        }
        else if (premiuminfo.TryGetProperty("name", out var _) && (premiuminfo.TryGetProperty("given_name", out var _) || !premiuminfo.TryGetProperty("family_name", out var _)))
        {
            processingResult = new ProcessingResultObject { ErrorResult = new ErrorResult { error = ErrorTypes.invalid_request.ToString(), error_description = "name and (given_name, family_name) both exists in claims" }, StatusCode = 400 };
        }
        else if (!premiuminfo.TryGetProperty("address", out var _) && (!premiuminfo.TryGetProperty("houseno_or_housename", out var _) || !premiuminfo.TryGetProperty("postal_code", out var _)))
        {
            processingResult = new ProcessingResultObject { ErrorResult = new ErrorResult { error = ErrorTypes.invalid_request.ToString(), error_description = "address is missing in claims" }, StatusCode = 400 };
        }
        else if (premiuminfo.TryGetProperty("address", out var _) && (premiuminfo.TryGetProperty("houseno_or_housename", out var _) || premiuminfo.TryGetProperty("postal_code", out var _)))
        {
            processingResult = new ProcessingResultObject { ErrorResult = new ErrorResult { error = ErrorTypes.invalid_request.ToString(), error_description = "address and (houseno_or_housename, postal_code) both exists in claims" }, StatusCode = 400 };
        }
        else
        {
            processingResult.Result = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        processingResult = new ProcessingResultObject { ErrorResult = new ErrorResult { error = ErrorTypes.invalid_request.ToString(), error_description = "premiuminfo are not found in claims" }, StatusCode = 400 };
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    processingResult = new ProcessingResultObject { ErrorResult = new ErrorResult { error = ErrorTypes.invalid_request.ToString(), error_description = "premiuminfo are not found in claims. ex" }, StatusCode = 400 };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for [TryGetProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement.trygetproperty?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Json_JsonElement_TryGetProperty_System_String_System_Text_Json_JsonElement__)

> TryGetProperty(ReadOnlySpan, JsonElement)
>
> Looks for a property
> named propertyName in the current object, returning a value that
> indicates whether or not such a property exists. When the property
> exists, the method assigns its value to the value argument.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Newtonsoft.Json library that gives you more functionality. You can parse your main json and then the string object you have for claims as well to access the properties within claims.

**example**

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
var claims = JObject.Parse(obj["claims"].ToString());

Console.WriteLine(claims["premiuminfo"].ToString()); // Prints entire claim
Console.WriteLine(claims["premiuminfo"]["country"].ToString()); // prints the country.
```